# Can I compile and run cuda program in windows 7 without visual studio?

Tags: windows, cuda, nvidia

Currently I am new to CUDA I have NVIDIA tesla c2075 card I install CUDA toolkit for windows. Now I don't have visual studio. I want to run and test CUDA programs without using visual studio.

Comment: You can just download and install the free Visual Studio Express edition from http://microsoft.com

Comment: It's now known as Visual Studio Community, if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only [officially supported compiler for use with CUDA on windows](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#windows) is cl.exe, the compiler that ships with visual studio.  It also comes with the [express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-2010-express) (free) versions of visual studio.  Is there a reason you don't want to do this?

You can also get the tools and set up a command-line compile environment using the [Microsoft Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

Comment: I wish there was a way to set it up using gcc or mingw. I just hate using VS (and it takes up too much space on my SSD boot drive). My usual development environment on my Mac is using Textmate + scons for building. Much more flexible that way. 

But right now, NVIDIA just doesn't seem to want to do it.

Comment: As for why you would not want to install VS if it could be avoided: If all you need is the compiler the IDE will just take up a lot of hard disk space.